# What happens with guest VMs if host running Vagrant is powered off?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

Imaging I am running a Virtual Machine guest (VM) managed by Vagrant and hosted by VirtualBox on Windows. What happens if the HOST is abruptly powered off? Is whatever data that has been added/updated to the VM lost? If this is the case, must I run `vagrant halt` to insure nothing is lost? Perhaps `vagrant suspend` would be sufficient?

Thank you for any insights or recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

If the host crashes, the VirtualBox VMs will end to aborted state, but in many cases `vagrant up` should be enough to get them running again.

If you're unlucky and the VM got corrupted it might be that only destroying and creating it again helps. But that's why you make all modifications via [provisioners](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/index.html), don't you? =)

`vagrant halt` or `vagrant suspend` won't do nothing in this case, as the VM is not running.

And if the host is just shut down normally, the running VMs should be suspended by recent VirtualBox versions.

Comment: So would it be fair to say that the normal behavior of an abrupt power loss of the Host would be that guest VM data files would be persisted?

Comment: Yes, but the data could be corrupted if the power loss happened in the middle of a write operation.

Comment: It would be normal to expect some corruption if power loss occurred in the middle of a write operation. What would be troubling would be if, rather than a corrupted file, the WHOLE VM would be no longer bootable!! :(

Answer (score 1):

If the host suffers from a power loss, the same happens to all the running guests as if they were suddenly powered off.

Data loss can happen, but it depends on the file system mount options, results can vary.

For Linux VMs using `ext4` as its main file system, I'd recommend using `data=journal` instead of the default `data=ordered` and turn write barriers on by using `barrier=1`. The above can be done in `/etc/fstab`. This will help to minimize the possibility of data loss but it is NOT 100% guaranteed.

HTH

Comment: Suggestions for how to minimize the risk of VM corruption are interesting! If you have any references, please share. Thank You :)

Comment: Some ref on `ext4` write barriers https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ext4.txt RHEL 7 doc https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ext4mount.html

Comment: There is a separate chapter in RHEL7 doc talking about writer barriers: https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch-writebarriers.html